# Python Tkinter UI freezes even after replacing sleep() to root.after()

Tags: python, tkinter

4-5 Seconds after running the tkinter based program in Python, it freezes. I'm not using any sleep() statement in my program. Have a look at the code below.

```
    def sleeper(tim):
        print("sleep Timer")
        tex.update_idletasks()

    def countdown():#countdown logic
        global key
        global t
        global timeformatToBePub
        timeformat=""

        if (key==0):
            mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
            timeformat = '{:02d}{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            timeformatToBePub = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print(timeformat, end='\n')
            ###sevenSeg(list(timeformat))#pass list of time characters as argument
            top.after(1000,sleeper(1))
            #tex.update_idletasks()
            #top.update_idletasks()
            t -= 1

            tex.delete('1.0',tk.END)
            #top.after(1000,sleeper(1))
            tex.insert(tk.END,"Self destruction mode                 activated\n"+timeformatToBePub+"\n")
        if ((key==0) and(timeformat=="0001")):
            tex.delete('1.0',tk.END)
            top.after(1000,sleeper(1))
            tex.insert(tk.END,"At least you tried...\n Game over!\n Type         restart to restart the game")
            PlaySound(1)
            publish("dev1",        ("dev1,"+answers_list[0]+","+answers_list[1])+","+timeformatToBePub)
            top.after(1000,sleeper(1))
            restarter()#restarts the program
        top.after(2000,countdown())
```

What is the reason of program not responding after few seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other problems, but one glaring problem is that you are misusing `after`. After requires a *callable*.

Consider this line of code:

```
top.after(1000,sleeper(1))
```

It is functionally identical to this:

```
sleeper(1)
top.after(1000, None)
```

... which is also functionally identical to this:

```
sleeper(1)
sleep(1)
```

To properly use `after` you must pass a reference to the function. Additional arguments can be passed by including them in the call to `after`. For example:

```
top.after(1000, sleeper, 1)
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver man! I was scratching my head since last two days to figure out the problem and just forgot to pass a reference to the function. Now everything seems working fine.